# GLSL check if fragment is on geometry

Tags: geometry, shader, glsl, depth

I am currently writing the positions of my geometry to the RGB channels of `gl_FragColor` and I would like to write 1.0 to the alpha channel if the fragment is part of geometry, and 0.0 if its empty.

Is there a simple way to tell if a fragment is geometry or not? Maybe through `gl_FragCoord.z`?

thanks

Answer (score 3):

**Every** processed fragment is generated because the geometry is rendered. Fragments not belonging to the geometry rasterization result are not processed by the fragment shader.

So, the solution is very simple:

```
gl_FragColor.a = 1.0;
```

However, you need an RGBA texture.